# replacement of a string in xml

Tags: sed, grep, xml

I am trying to replace folder name value in an xml file.I am searching with required pattern using grep and replace the folder name value which is DF_GCSS with ABC_DEF which comes from a variable.Below mentioned statement i have used to replace only the folder name value but the output is not as expected.It is appending the variable data to the existing folder value

```
FLDR_NM=ABC_DEF
grep -i "<FOLDER NAME" file_name.xml |  sed 's/<FOLDER NAME="[Aa0-Zz9]"*/<FOLDER NAME="'$FLDR_NM'"/1g'
```

Output:

```
<FOLDER NAME="ABC_DEF"F_GCSS" GROUP="" OWNER="Administrator" SHARED="NOTSHARED" DESCRIPTION="" PERMISSIONS="rwx---r--" UUID="5ff15b2a">
```

Expected output:

```
<FOLDER NAME="ABC_DEF" GROUP="" OWNER="Administrator" SHARED="NOTSHARED" DESCRIPTION="" PERMISSIONS="rwx---r--" UUID="5ff15b2a">
```

Comment: is the folder name to begin with just `F_GCSS` ?

Comment: Any reason you have to use grep/sed, and not tools that deal properly with XML files (including possible line breaks)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided the current folder name can only be alphanumeric with underscores (`_`), this will work:

```
my_folder="ABC_DEF"; 
cat tmp.xml | sed -e "s/FOLDER NAME=\"[[:alnum:]_]*\"/FOLDER NAME\=\"$my_folder\"/g"
```

Folder name in `tmp.xml` is set to `F_GCSS`

output:

```
<FOLDER NAME="ABC_DEF" GROUP="" OWNER="Administrator" SHARED="NOTSHARED" DESCRIPTION="" PERMISSIONS="rwx---r--" UUID="5ff15b2a">
```